# cache data in python and sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, fastcgi, lighttpd

1. Using python(fastcgi),lighttpd,sqlite3 for server
2. Update data of sqlite3 every weekend.
3. Thats means, every user get the same data from server before weekend,and server query database for every user's request.
   My question is:
   Is there any way to cache data for users,server using cache data to response all users before updating data,not query database every time.
   Like using a global variable for a week,until update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cache such as memcached to store it once retrieved.